# code debugging: Nil object is not Nil

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode5

I am currently having a strange problem with my xCode 5.0: an object appears to be nil in the console, but at the same time its able to be accessed by code.

[image: pic 1: nil downloader with all properties set to nil]
[image: pic 1.1: nil]

**pic 1: the object appears to be nil**

[image: pic 2: output of NSLog]
**pic 2: output of NSLog(@"%@", imgDownloader) is not nil, the delegate is also getting called normally**

By the way, I never intent to make this object nil, you can see from the code that I initialised the object like how I should, but somehow it ended up as nil in the console.

Why is it like this? Is this a bug in the new xCode?

Comment: The Xcode debugger variables view is sometimes plain wrong. Try `po ...` in the debugger console instead.

Comment: Taking a wild guess here, could it be that it is on background thread? Or am I totally wrong here @MartinR?

Comment: Hi Mikael, no it is not on a background thread.

Comment: Sure looks like a bug. Tried to reproduce it with custom class, cannot.

Comment: There's lot of bugs with Clang and debug symbol + Xcode. Dunno wich one is responsible. Sometimes local variables never appears, and sometime you can't output them because the object is "nil", even if in the breakpoint stack it appears it is not. So that you need to re-run with logs inside. Seems it worked better with gdb

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably building in release mode, change the build mode to debug in the scheme.

Comment: Exactly! I forgot to change the scheme setting back.